# Azure SQL DWH: Can connect with Login, but not user

Tags: sql-server, azure, t-sql, azure-sql-database, azure-synapse

I am currently setting up some users for my Azure SQL DWH. I have created a Login at server level and a User at my database. However, I am getting a login failed message if I try to use my database user. If I use the Login I have created it works just fine. This Login also only has access to the views I have granted it access to. Am I missing something really obvious or is there something different about logins and roles in SQL DWH?

```
CREATE LOGIN Login WITH PASSWORD = 'Password';
CREATE USER User FROM LOGIN Login;
```

Comment: I am not sure about dw,but for sqlserver you can't login with an user unles it is contained user,i **think** same applies to dw

Comment: I guess that makes sense. Given that the docs on contained databases does not apply to SQL DWH,https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/contained-databases, it seems like your assumption is correct. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use “user” as the name of the new database login because is a reserved word. Additionally add the login to the datareader role and try again.

```
EXEC sp_addrolemember 'db_datareader', 'newdatabaseuser';
```

Try to login to the SQL Data Warehouse server without specifying the database. If you are able to connect then with above statement you may solve the issue.

If you are trying to get connected from an application please make sure you are using appropriate drivers. Learn more about it [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-data-warehouse/sql-data-warehouse-connect-overview).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi Alberto,
I am not actually calling my login "Login", and my User "User", that is to show how I've create them. I've added my user to the datareader role, and tried to not specify database. Unfortunately that does not make any difference, and I still get a login failed if I use the user I've created. Works fine with the login so it seems like TheGameiswar's theory is the case.

Comment: Do you know that you need to run the CREATE LOGIN statement on the master database and the CREATE USER should be run on the SQL Azure Data Warehouse specific database? Please read this article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-data-warehouse/sql-data-warehouse-overview-manage-security